# Control Hulu playback with Universal/Media Center Remote?

Tags: windows-media-center, universal-remote, logitech-universal-remote

Is it possible to control video playback on Hulu and broadcaster web sites (nbc.com, cbs.com, etc) with a Universal or Media Center remote?

I have a Logitech Harmony 659 remote I use for Windows Media Center, and I have a cordless mouse I can use, but it would be nice to not have to try and find the "Pause" button during playback, and use the remote instead. If not, is there a way to access these sites via WMC plugin or anything? My browser is Firefox 3.5 on Windows Vista (soon to be 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as controlling Hulu, Hulu has a [desktop application](http://www.hulu.com/labs/hulu-desktop), offering a very complete experience that is designed to work with Media Center remotes.

I wouldn't expect, or am not aware of, a method for controlling Flash content such as web-specific videos with a remote through the browser though.

Comment: I use the hulu desktop app and it works great with a MC remote.  there is also an app out there so you can add a shortcut to Hulu Desktop from MC.

Comment: This works for me. I'll have to give them feedback to allow pause with the actual "pause" button rather than the "enter" button, though.